# Can't store this in file

Tags: python

Help me I want to store a name and score in a file.

```
name = ("Chiken")
score = 7
classroom_num = int(input("Please enter your classroom number"))
f = open("Classroom %d.txt","w") % (classroom_num)
f.write(name, score)
f.close()
```

Comment: `f = open("Classroom %d..txt" %classroom_num, 'w')` and `f.write(name + " " + str(score) + '\n')`

Comment: When you post questions about Python, please include the full tracebck of the error you received, if you did received one. This code has a couple of errors that should have caused exceptions to be raised.